# How to get multiple column header names using aoColumn sTitle attribute in data tables

Tags: jquery, node.js, datatables

I able to give only one sTitle Name.But I want to get two column header names.one is "File Name" and the other is "Date" using aoColumn sTitle attribute in dataTable.

How can I achieve this.Can anyone please help me out ...

The code in app.js :

```
        "aoColumns": [{"sTitle":"File Name", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;"  + data.Name +"</a>";
              } else {
                return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_balnk'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +" "+data.Date+"</a>";
              }
            }
          },

         {"sTitle":"Date", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return data.Date;
              } else {
                return data.Date;
              }
            }
          }
        ]   
     };
```

My app.js :

```
(function($){

        var extensionsMap = {
                      ".zip" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".gz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".bz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".xz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".rar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tar" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tgz" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".tbz2" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".7z" : "fa-file-archive-o",         
                      ".mp3" : "fa-file-audio-o",         
                      ".cs" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".c++" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".cpp" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".js" : "fa-file-code-o",         
                      ".xls" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".xlsx" : "fa-file-excel-o",         
                      ".png" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".jpeg" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".gif" : "fa-file-image-o",         
                      ".mpeg" : "fa-file-movie-o",         
                      ".pdf" : "fa-file-pdf-o",         
                      ".ppt" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".pptx" : "fa-file-powerpoint-o",         
                      ".txt" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".log" : "fa-file-text-o",         
                      ".doc" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                      ".docx" : "fa-file-word-o",         
                    };

  function getFileIcon(ext) {
    return ( ext && extensionsMap[ext.toLowerCase()]) || 'fa-file-o';
  }



  var currentPath = null;
   var options = {
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
         "sScrollY":"250px",
      "fnCreatedRow" :  function( nRow, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    if (!aData.IsDirectory) return;
    var path = aData.Path;
    $(nRow).bind("click", function(e){
        $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
            table.fnClearTable();
            table.fnAddData(data);
            currentPath = path;
        });


        $.get('/directory?path='+ path).then(function(data){        
            $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
           //$("#showDiv").hide();
         });         
    e.preventDefault();
    });
},

        "aoColumns": [{"sTitle":"File Name", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return "<a href='#' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-folder'></i>&nbsp;"  + data.Name +"</a>";
              } else {
                return "<a href='/" + data.Path + "' target='_balnk'><i class='fa " + getFileIcon(data.Ext) + "'></i>&nbsp;" + data.Name +" "+data.Date+"</a>";
              }
            }
          },

         {"sTitle":"Date", "mData": null, "bSortable": false, "sClass": "head0", "sWidth": "55px",
            "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
              if (data.IsDirectory) {
                return data.Date;
              } else {
                return data.Date;
              }
            }
          }
        ]   
     };

  var table = $(".linksholder").dataTable(options);

  $.get('/files').then(function(data){
      table.fnClearTable();
      table.fnAddData(data);
  });

$.get('/directory').then(function(data){        
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);
   $("#showDiv").hide();
});

$(".up").bind("click", function(e){
    if (!currentPath) return;
    var idx = currentPath.lastIndexOf("/");
    var path =currentPath.substr(0, idx);
    $.get('/files?path='+ path).then(function(data){
        table.fnClearTable();
        table.fnAddData(data);
        currentPath = path;
    });

$.get('/directory?path='+path).then(function(data){
    $("input[name='location']").val(data.directory);

 });

});
})(jQuery);
```

current Format :

[image]

Comment: You can use `"sTitle":"File Name / Date"` but I think you rather need a separate column for file/directory date.

Comment: Is it the right way of adding the column.Please check the edited code

Comment: Can you show how your data produced by `/files` looks like?

Comment: I have posted a screen shot.Please check it once.

Comment: But my requirement is ,if we browse a directory,I should get the file  names along with their date in the directory.But I'm getting sub directories also.